# Converting float strings with 0 tenths and hundredths to integers in python 2.7

Tags: python

Let's say that we know for sure that all the strings are some representation of a number. The foo function returns the number value of the string we passed in. I also want to check if the passed string representation of a number is an integer or a float.
However I'm not sure if this is the most elegant way of doing this. Is there a simpler/cleaner way?

```
def foo(arg):
        if arg.endswith('.00'):
            arg3 = arg3[:-3]
        try:
            arg3 = int(arg3)
        except:
            arg3 = float(arg3)

        return arg


    arg1 = '3456.26'
    arg2 = '100.00'

    num1 = foo(arg1)
    num2 = foo(arg2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Floating point numbers have an [`is_integer` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#float.is_integer), which tells you whether they're equal to an integer or not:

```
>>> (1.23).is_integer()
False
>>> (1.0).is_integer()
True
```

Therefore you could use this to write something like:

```
def to_number(s):
    """Converts a string to a number."""
    f = float(s)
    return int(f) if f.is_integer() else f
```

*(note that I have avoided the use of ["bare `except`"](http://blog.codekills.net/2011/09/29/the-evils-of--except--/))*. In use:

```
>>> for x in ('1.23', '123', '1.00', 'foo'):
    print x, to_number(x)


1.23 1.23
123 123
1.00 1
foo

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 2, in <module>
    print x, to_number(x)
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 5, in to_number
    f = float(s)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: foo
```

Comment: you can simplify removing the try...except section

Comment: @bilbo you're right, of course; that's a hangover from an earlier version where I'd misunderstood the question!